# Handle multiple "identical" inputs on a page in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I'm learning React and Redux by writing an app to do results for canoe/kayak races. I have a page that shows bunch of boat categories, and the classes for each category, with the option to add new classes.[image]
(Yes, it's not pretty. Better ui paradigms are welcomed.)

I put out each boat category in a map, and then the classes within each category in another map, and put the "New Boat Class" input in each one using:

```
         <ListGroup.Item key='add'>
            <Form.Row>
              <Col>
                <Form.Control placeholder='New Boat Class' ref='newClass' />
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  variant='primary'
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.props.onAddClass(bcat.category, this.refs.newClass.value);
                    this.refs.newClass.value = '';
                  }}
                >Add New Boat Class
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Form.Row>
          </ListGroup.Item>
```

The problem is that I'm using "old style" refs to get the values of the input, but unfortunately the onAddClass function gets the value from the last one, no matter which button is pressed. I want each button to get the value from the Form.Control next to it, not the last one. How can I do this?

**Update** One approach I've come up with that works, but it looks like I'm probably violating some principle of react-redux. I use the boat category name as the ref:

```
              <ListGroup.Item key='add'>
                <Form.Row>
                  <Col>
                    <Form.Control
                      placeholder='New Boat Class'
                      ref={bcat.category}
                    />
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Button
                      variant='primary'
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.props.onAddClass(bcat.category, this.refs[bcat.category].value);
                        this.refs[bcat.category].value = '';
                      }}
                    >Add New Boat Class
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Form.Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
```

Comment: Why are you using refs at all to keep track of form values?  It seems like you should be using `state` to keep track of everything.

Comment: @MatthewMoran I've still got the problem of distinguishing between a bunch of identical inputs and matching the right input with the right button. How would I do this?

Comment: When you map over them to render them, you'd use their index to keep track of them.  The change handler could accept the value and the index of the specific input.

Comment: You keep talking about redux. Your problem has nothing to do with redux.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewMoran I converted to using `state`. I didn't use index, I used the category name, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @MatthewMoran's suggestion, I made the following changes.

First, I added a constructor with current state:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { };
  }
```

Then I added a method to update the state:

```
  setBoatClass (category, value) {
    this.setState({ [category]: value });
  }
```

Then in the `Form.Control` I track the current value, and in the button I use the state value:

```
                  <ListGroup.Item key='add'>
                    <Form.Row>
                      <Col>
                        <Form.Control
                          placeholder='New Boat Class'
                          onChange={e => this.setBoatClass(bcat.category, e.target.value)}
                          value={this.state[bcat.category]}
                        />
                      </Col>
                      <Col>
                        <Button
                          variant='primary'
                          onClick={() => {
                            this.props.onAddClass(bcat.category, this.state[bcat.category]);
                            this.setState({ [bcat.category]: '' });
                          }}
                        >Add New Boat Class
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
```